# Get current timestamp in PHP in phpmyadmin format

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

In phpadmin we can assign default value as current timestamp for a field.
How can we generate timestamp in similar format in php.
For eg.: 2014-09-07 03:18:35.000000

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yourdate);`

Comment: Your date... a timestamp. `time()` returns the current timestamp

Comment: Yeah sorry should have clarified, a timestamp. Or you can do `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('a valid date string'));`

Answer (score 6):

Pretty simple in PHP:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

Where [time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) outputs the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch. It'll be based on your server clock. You can replace `time()` with any other timestamp or PHP function that generates a timestamp, like [mktime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), [DateTime::getTimestamp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php), etc.